# I can't switch hdmi-stereo to analog-stereo

Tags: graphic-drivers, drivers, audio, ubuntu, hdmi

I can't find the option to change audio device.
Only see [image]

my goal is to use the audio jack on my motherboard

I run

```
pacmd list-cards
```

result:

```
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_29_00.1>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 7
        properties:
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfcf60000 irq 68"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:29:00.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:29:00.1/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1002"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
                device.product.id = "aaf0"
                device.product.name = "Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580]"
                device.string = "0"
                device.description = "Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580]"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        profiles:
                output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5200, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra5: Digital Stereo (HDMI 6) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra5: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra5: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo-extra3>
        sinks:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_29_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra3/#50: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580] Digital Stereo (HDMI 4)
        sources:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_29_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra3.monitor/#50: Monitor of Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580] Digital Stereo (HDMI 4)
        ports:
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                device.product.name = "TV Monitor"
                hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-5: HDMI / DisplayPort 6 (priority 5400, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

and I run

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

result:

```
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 50
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_29_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra3>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE 
        priority: 9030
        volume: front-left: 32889 /  50% / -17,97 dB,   front-right: 32889 /  50% / -17,97 dB
                balance 0,00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0,00 ms
        max request: 0 KiB
        max rewind: 0 KiB
        monitor source: 50
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 2
        configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 341,33 ms
        card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_29_00.1>
        module: 7
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "HDMI 3"
                alsa.id = "HDMI 3"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "9"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfcf60000 irq 68"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:29:00.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:29:00.1/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1002"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
                device.product.id = "aaf0"
                device.product.name = "Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580]"
                device.string = "hdmi:0,3"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo-extra3"
                device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI 4)"
                device.description = "Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580] Digital Stereo (HDMI 4)"
                alsa.mixer_name = "ATI R6xx HDMI"
                alsa.components = "HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100700"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        ports:
                hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                device.product.name = "TV Monitor"
        active port: <hdmi-output-3>
```

I cant's set wit

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
```

Neither

It sounds perfect from the monitor but I need it to recognize the audio and microphone jacks to be able to use headphones

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help you but more advanced audio control you can have by installing and using **PulseAudio Volume Control**. Check the AppStore.